# If I create a transient property in the model, isn't this managed by core data then?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Just to grok this: If I had a transient property, lets say averagePrice, and I mark that as "transient" in the data modeler: This will not be persistet, and no column will be created in SQLite for that?

And: If I make my own NSManagedObject subclass with an averagePrice property, does it make any sense to model that property in the xcdatamodel file? Would it make a difference if I would simply create a property in my subclass and not model that in the entity?

(I think: yes, it doesn't matter at all ... but not sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transient properties are handled by the undomanager for example.
In addition changing transient properties makes the document "dirty" if you work in a document based application.

Creating the property only in your subclass does not affect the whole core data stack at all.
It depends on your needs which solution to choose

[Article on transient properties in core data](http://2pi.dk/tech/cocoa/transient_properties.html)

Comment: what do you mean by "dirty"? Can you give an example?

Comment: the document indicates unsaved changes, even if only transient properties are modified